# Using one resusable component vs Importing the file everytime in terms of performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning Reactjs and I saw the instructor splitting the repetitive code into reusable components. In terms of clean code I know that this is the best approach but what came to my mind are the import statements and does they impact performance. For example:

** If I'm building 3 forms using Formik Library and I have a reusable component that had Formik imported once and I never import it again in the other files. ( Here Formik is imported once )

VS.

** If I import formik each time in the 3 components without using a reusable component ( Formik imported 3 time )

Other than the ugly repitition of code does that have to do anything with the performance or bundling just makes both approaches the same in terms of app size and speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is bundled - Formik **is** only imported once. Less code (reusable components) is almost always preferable to more code (single-use components).

If your app imports Formik in a hundred different places for various hooks, etc - it still only exists in your bundle once. Your instructor sounds decent, listen to them.

Comment: So size and performance are the same in both approaches?

Comment: If all else is equal, yes. There's a trick to writing re-usable components: Don't try to write them. Write a component to do what you need and the next time you need one similar to one you've already created, re-write the one you already created so that it can be used in both places.